How do I tell curl to try other protocols?
I tried downloading an Aeroméxico news item using
curl "https://www.aeromexico.com/en-us/am-news/new-Rome-route" -s --trace-ascii -

But it reports
== Info: HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

Which options do I need to supply to curl to have it try all available protocols? HTTP2 doesn't seem to be working.

You can’t ask curl to try all available protocols for a single request, but you can force it to use a specific version of HTTP:
curl --http1.1 "https://www.aeromexico.com/en-us/am-news/new-Rome-route" -s --trace-ascii -

The available variants are --http1.0 (or -0), --http1.1, --http2, and --http3.
The similar --http0.9 option doesn’t force HTTP/0.9, it only tells curl to accept 0.9 (headerless) connections.

On curl v7.88.1, it still seems to use HTTP2 if I supply --http0.9. Why?

Ah, --http0.9 is different, it doesn’t force 0.9, it only allows it.
